# Using Urban Terror 4.2, how can I connect to a 4.1 server?

Tags: networking, urban-terror

I've just downloaded, installed and configured [Urban Terror 4.2.009](http://www.urbanterror.info/news/395-4-2-update-4-2-009/). And I would like to go play on [Sexy CTF](http://sexysctf.net/) server 1 which, [as far as I know](http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/188.40.71.213:27960/), is a Urban Terror 4.1.1 server.

Contrary to what I expect, this server isn't visible in the servers list of my client. What can I do to make it visible ? Or should i connect by directly entering its IP address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't connect to 4.1 server because the 4.2 version isn't retro-compatible with older versions, due to major changes (weapons available, skins, etc.).

Since January 1st, 2014, masters for the [4.1 servers are even shut down](http://www.urbanterror.info/news/437-end-of-the-4-1-era/), so it's became impossible to list every servers using this version. You should move forward and play only on 4.2 servers :)